# ActiveReports, Box to be fixed at bottom of Page 2

Tags: .net, activereports

I have an ActiveReports report where on the second page of the document, a paragraph must be at the bottom of the page.  There is a PageFooter already which appears on every page.  I just have a specific paragraph that when it appears, must be at the bottom of a page to mark the end of a section in the document.  Has anyone experienced this problem before and any ideas on how to go about it?

In addition, the footer also includes the page number, the date and document name so I can't just hide the page footer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved by handling the PageFooter's Format event. Just check the PageNumber and set the Visible property of the TextBox containing the paragraph to true.

```
private void pageFooter_Format(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.PageNumber == 2)            
            this.textBox3.Visible = true;            
        else
            this.textBox3.Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention that the page footer can't be just hidden because the page footer includes additional information which has to be shown on every page.  I've updated the issue above with the missing information/

Comment: @MiscellaneousUser please note that code Abdias provided uses the PageFooter_Format event, but it doesn't hide/display the PageFooter itself, rather the textbox that would contain your text.

Comment: Managed to get the text in the right place BUT I had to move a subreport out of the Details section to a GroupFooter section.  The subreport no longer displays in the GroupFooter section.

Comment: In which event are you initializing the subreport? Have you tried it in the GroupFooter's Format event. If it's still not working, please share your code.